# InterlockedExchange vs InterlockedCompareExchange spin locks

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I've written a basic spin lock (see below) using InterlockedExchange.  However I've seen a lot of implementations use InterlockedCompareExchange instead.  Is mine incorrect in some unforeseen way and if not what are the pro's and cons of each way (if indeed there are any)?

PS I know the sleep is expensive and I'd want to have an attempt count before I call it.

```
class SpinLock
{
public:

    SpinLock() : m_lock( 0 ) {}
    ~SpinLock(){}

    void Lock()
    {
        while( InterlockedExchange( &m_lock, 1 ) == 1 )
        { 
            Sleep( 0 ); 
        }
    }

    void Unlock()
    {
        InterlockedExchange( &m_lock, 0 );
    }

private:
    volatile unsigned int m_lock;
};
```

Comment: If you are going to resort to a system call for Sleep(0), you may as well fall back on a kernel lock.

Comment: What's the point of ` == 1` in the `Unlock()`?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a spinlock that it "spins", rather than sleeps when the lock is busy.

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect.  It is not a lock.  It is not a spinlock either.  Don't write this yourself.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes and no.  If you never enter the system, you can easily spin forever, blocking whoever has the lock from progressing.

Comment: That would definitely be a problem on a single processor system - but then spinlocks are typically not used on single processor systems.

Comment: @Martin James: I'm not interested in the Sleep(0) I just left it in there to make sure it logically didn't deadlock.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Sorry my bad just left that in there from the original code it was part of a 'verify'.

Comment: In `Unlock` you should check that the value returned is indeed `0` in an assert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is very little difference between CMPXCHG and XCHG (which is the x86 instructions that you'd get from the two intrinsic functions you mention).

I think the main difference is that in a SMP system with a lot of contention on the lock, you don't get a bunch of writes when the value is already "locked" - which means that the other processors don't have to read back a value that is already there in the cache.

In a debug build, you'd also want to ensure that `Unlock()` is only called from the current owner of the lock!

Comment: While not the case here, there are a lot of algorithms which require CMPXCHG, and which cannot be made to work with XCHG.  (Atomic reference counting comes to mind.)

Comment: Cheers Mat yes I do check in the unlock in debug hence the accidentally left in '== 1' (now removed).

Answer (score 6):

First of all, `InterlockedExchange` takes a `LONG`. Please repeat after me: a `LONG` isn't the same an an `int`. This may seem like a small thing but it can cause you grief.

Now, to elaborate a little on what Mats Petersson said:

Your spinlock will have *horrible* performance since the InterlockedExchange loop in `Lock` will modify the `m_lock` variable unconditionally, causing a lot of work to be done by the processors behind the scenes to maintain cache coherency.

To make matters worse, by not ensuring that your `m_lock` variable is on a cache line by itself, the above effect is amplified and could affect other data, unlucky enough to share the cache line with the instance of your spinlock.

These are just two moderately subtle issues with this code. There are others. The simple fact is that locks aren't easy to get right, and you shouldn't be implementing custom locking primitives. Please don't reinvent the wheel. Use the facilities provided to you by the operating system. It's unlikely they *themselves* are a bottleneck.

If you do find you have a performance issue (that is, you have profiling data that suggests a performance bottleneck) first focus on algorithmic changes and on improving parallelization and reducing lock contention. If the problem persists *then and only then* look elsewhere.

Comment: Heh - given the many examples of lock misuse on SO and elsewhere, (esp. locking over lengthy operations), I would expect that spinlocks would cause more problems than they fix in a large number of cases.